# Setting Width by Pixel for Mobile Phones

Tags: android, html, css, iphone

Most high-end smartphones have a 720 X1280 or 640 X 1136 resolution these days.

If I set the width of an `img` element to 360px, will it fill half the screen on these phones? If so, do I have to use different layouts for different resolutions for mobile phones?

What about `font-size`? If you set it by pixel, will smartphones interpret it literally? A 10px font size will be big enough in a 320 X 480 screen, but unreadable in a 720 X1280 resolution.

Comment: Read this and fear no more:

[PX vs DP vs DiP vs SP][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to have a layout on mobile devices for different resolutions, one quick and time-effective way to get started with is to code your layout with your desired screen width in mind, and then have this line in your header, where `720` will be the width you coded for originally:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=720, user-scalable=no" />
```

The browser will scale the layout to fit its screen.

You can have the line as the following too:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=720, user-scalable=yes" />
```

This will enable the user to zoom in (and out)

With this, you can have a maximum zoom defined and permitted for the user:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=720, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
```

With `maximum-scale=1` you allow the user to zoom in up to the original width of the layout and no further.

Answer (score 0):

yeah if you work on pixel thats what android will do. however highly not recommended. DPI is a much better unit.

*If so, do I have to use different layouts for different resolutions for mobile phones?*

not really

*If you set it by pixel, will smartphones interpret it literally?*

Yeah they will interpret it in px, but again not recommended